# Postresql syntax error at or near 'FROM' in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to do psql subquery like below:

```
SELECT invoices.*, contractors.name AS contractor
FROM (SELECT id AS resource_id,
    'OutgoingInvoice' AS resource_type,
    creation_date AS date,
    number AS description,
    total_gross_amount_cents,
    total_discount_amount_cents,
    'false' AS credit_note,
    created_at
FROM outgoing_invoices
WHERE customer_id = 1
AND payment_status = 'unpaid'
AND cancelled_outgoing_invoice_id IS NULL
AND draft = 'false') invoices
FROM outgoing_invoices
WHERE customer_id = 1
AND payment_status = 'unpaid'
AND cancelled_outgoing_invoice_id IS NULL
AND draft = 'false'
```

And got stuck here:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 15: FROM outgoing_invoices
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you can't have two `FROM` clauses

Answer (score 3):

You have duplicate FROM outgoing_invoices clauses.
It may be helpful to indent query to make it clearer:

```
SELECT
    invoices.*,
    contractors.name AS contractor
FROM (
        SELECT
            id AS resource_id,
            'OutgoingInvoice' AS resource_type,
            creation_date AS date,
            number AS description,
            total_gross_amount_cents,
            total_discount_amount_cents,
            'false' AS credit_note,
            created_at
        FROM outgoing_invoices
        WHERE customer_id = 1
            AND payment_status = 'unpaid'
            AND cancelled_outgoing_invoice_id IS NULL
            AND draft = 'false'
    ) invoices
FROM outgoing_invoices
WHERE customer_id = 1
AND payment_status = 'unpaid'
AND cancelled_outgoing_invoice_id IS NULL
AND draft = 'false'
```

So in your case it should be something like

```
SELECT
        invoices.*,
        contractors.name AS contractor
    FROM (
            SELECT
                id AS resource_id,
                'OutgoingInvoice' AS resource_type,
                creation_date AS date,
                number AS description,
                total_gross_amount_cents,
                total_discount_amount_cents,
                'false' AS credit_note,
                created_at
            FROM outgoing_invoices
            WHERE customer_id = 1
                AND payment_status = 'unpaid'
                AND cancelled_outgoing_invoice_id IS NULL
                AND draft = 'false'
        ) invoices
```